# WiFi repeater with a single WiFi adapter in Debian

Tags: debian, wifi

Is it possible to create a WiFi repeater with a single WiFi adapter in Debian , to increase the range of my WiFi network?

Comment: +GAD3R Sorry I'm not sure what you would call it. Maybe a WiFi booster? Something which connects to a WiFi network and acts as a second access point to that network. Essentially extending the range of the WiFi network.

Comment: e,g: create a WiFi hotspot from the same wifi card ? can be helpful ?

Comment: Yes, connect to a WiFi network and create a hotspot on the same WiFi adapter.

Comment: As a side-note, a wifi adapter can only use on a single channel at a time, which means the AP will use the same frequency on both sides, thus cause interference with its source.  It may not be that bad but it will surely lower the maximum wifi bandwidth.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Interesting, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To increase the range of your WiFi network, you can create an access point from the same wifi card.

Install the required packages

```
apt-get install build-essential git
```

Install [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap):

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
make install
```

Start the service and enable it :

```
systemctl start create_ap
systemctl enable create_ap
```

To create an AP :

> Internet sharing from the same WiFi interface:

```
create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

**Update**

[linux-wifi-hotspot](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot) provide a graphical interface to create a wifi hotspot for the `create_ap` command line tool:

```
sudo apt install -y libgtk-3-dev libqrencode-dev build-essential gcc g++ pkg-config make \
hostapd iptables dnsmasq git

git clone https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot
cd linux-wifi-hotspot
make
sudo make install
```

> You can launch the GUI by searching for "Wifi Hotspot" in the Application Menu or using the terminal with:

```
wihotspot
```

> The wihotspot GUI uses `create_ap` to create and manage access points. This service and core logic was originally created by [@oblique](http://github.com/oblique), and are now maintained in this repository.

> Start the hotspot service on startup (using your saved configuration) with:

```
systemctl enable create_ap
```

Debian package:

A debian binary is available [here](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot/releases/tag/v3.5.1):

```
wget https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot/releases/download/v3.5.1/linux-wifi-hotspot_3.5.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./linux-wifi-hotspot_3.5.1_amd64.deb
```

dependencies:

```
libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0)
iw (>= 5.4)
iproute2 (>= 5.0)
```

[image]

Comment: I see under there features list "You can create an AP with the same interface you are getting your Internet connection." which is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I would up-vote you too but I don't have enough reputation on this stack-exchange.